# Summing multiple columns in a list?

Tags: python, csv

```
Name,A,B,C,D
Fred,1,3,4,3
Adam,1,4,1,2
Moo,4,2,3,2
```

So I want to sum this csv input by each column and then find the average before putting it in a list.

So for the above sample input, the list would be ['2','3','2.667','2.333'] for A,B,C,D respectively.
I thought of creating a list for each column and then finding the average before appending it to a pre-created list, but it didn't work.

```py
import csv
line_count = 0
first_line = True
final_list = []
A = []
B = []
C = []
D = []

for row in open("file.csv"):
values = row.strip().split(",")  
  if first_line:
    first_line = False
    else:
    line_count += 1
    A.append(int(values[1])) 
    sum_of_A = sum(A)
    average = [sum_of_A/line_count]
data.append(average)
```

But then after this, since the last line returns to the normal indentation space, I'm not sure how to return back into the loop to continue finding the average for the rest of the columns. I need it to be put into a list so I can rewrite it using the csv module into a new file, so any guidance is helpful.

Comment: *"So for the above sample input, the list would be `['2','3','8','7']`"* Did you mean `[2,3,2.667, 2.333]`?

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code. Badly indented python code is invalid python code.

Comment: You start with `import csv`, but then you don't use anything from the `csv` module. Perhaps you meant `with open('file.csv') as f: for row in csv.reader(f): ...`

Comment: @Stef Yes, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Why do you `import csv` and then never use it? Also, unless this is homework or an exercise and you _must_ do this using string split or csv, I suggest taking a look at pandas dataframes. You can read csv files using `pd.read_csv()`, it handles headers nicely, and you can calculate sums and averages of columns quickly and easily. [pandas get column average/mean](//stackoverflow.com/q/31037298/843953)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I think there is **a lot** of value into trying to understand how things work first, rather than jump in and use library functions that can solve every problem without a second thought.

Comment: @Stef I only pasted a chunk of code specific to the question,  I plan to use writer.writerow(data) at the end, the beginning is set up already!

Comment: @Stef which is why I said _"unless this is homework..."_

Comment: @PranavHosangadi, not really homework but I want to turn it into a spreadsheet later, so having it in a csv format is best suited

Comment: @NLT can you make sure the indentation in the question is what you have in your file? Because this code will throw `IndentationError` in multiple places.

Comment: @NLT in addition to writing to csv files with `writer`, the csv module is useful to read from csv files with `csv.reader`. Basically it will automatically perform the `.strip().split(',')` operations, but in a smarter/safer way. For instance, if a field contains a `,` inside quotes or escaped by a backslash, `.split(',')` will still split on that `,`, but `csv.reader` will correctly recognize that it shouldn't split on that `,`.

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the averages as you go using a list comprehension that zips the values with the averages you have so far.  Use the first line (column titles) as an initialization step since you have  to skip it anyway.

```
with open('file.csv') as f:
    for i,(_,*values) in enumerate(csv.reader(f)):
        if i: averages = [a+(float(v)-a)/i for a,v in zip(averages,values)]
        else: averages = [0]*len(values)

print(averages)
[2.0, 3.0, 2.6666666666666665, 2.3333333333333335]
```

If you're going to load the whole table in memory, you can get the averages from the nested list after loading it:

```
with open('file.csv') as f:
    data     = list(csv.reader(f))
    averages = [ sum(map(float,c))/len(c) 
                 for i,c in enumerate(zip(*data[1:])) if i ]

print(averages)
[2.0, 3.0, 2.6666666666666665, 2.3333333333333335]
```

Comment: That is a clever way to compute the average! Maybe it's the proper comp sci approach, but as someone who hacks code to solve other problems, I'd never seen it. For fun, I compared the time of our approaches (over 50,000 iterations) and yours seems to be about 2% faster. (Speaking to your first method. You added the second afterwards.)

Comment: The relatively expensive conditional `if i: ... else: ...` could be replaced by handling the first line of the file outside of the `for`-loop, using `next(f)` to get the first line.

Answer (score 0):

You can do everything in one loop.

```
import csv
line_count = 0
first_line = True
final_list = []
A = []
B = []
C = []
D = []

with open('test.csv') as input_file:
    for row in input_file:
        values = row.strip().split(",")
        if first_line:
            first_line = False
        else:
            line_count += 1
            A.append(int(values[1]))
            B.append(int(values[2]))
            C.append(int(values[3]))
            D.append(int(values[4]))
a_average = sum(A) / line_count
b_average = sum(B) / line_count
c_average = sum(C) / line_count
d_average = sum(D) / line_count
```

Now you have all the averages, you can do whatever you want.

Comment: Please don't recommend using `open` this way. You forgot to close the file after opening it.

Comment: Also, why build four lists of values if you're just going to sum them in the end? You could just compute the sum directly, using `A = 0` and `A += int(values[1])` rather than `A = []` and `A.append(int(values[1]))`

Comment: @Stef Don't worry, Stef. I do close my files a the end, even though I don't see the point of it, but that's probably because I only have around 1000 data to work with.

Comment: @NLT If you use the `with open('file.csv') as f:` construct, there is no risk of forgetting to close the file, and it will close automatically as soon as you exit the `with` block.

Answer (score 0):

You can just read in the file (without `csv`), split and sum:

```
with open("file.csv") as fid:
    # remove the "\n" from the end of each line, break line into list,
    # and remove first column
    data = [line.rstrip().split(",")[1:] for line in fid.readlines()]

data.pop(0) # remove first line (header)
n_rows = len(data)
n_columns = len(data[0])

summation = [(sum(int(row[column]) for row in data)) \
             for column in range(n_columns)]
average = [s / n_rows for s in summation]
```

`summation = [6, 9, 8, 7]`
`average = [2.0, 3.0, 2.6666666666666665, 2.3333333333333335]`